# Ajax post doesnt work with contentType

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot

I've got an editor that allows editing some text that has to be sent to my backend via Ajax Post request. This works fine so far with the only problem being that when I load the Text from the backend after saving it the encoding seems messed up (line breaks are not interpreted correctly). I tried setting the contentType flag in my Ajax request to `contentType: "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"` but after this change I'm getting this exception in my springboot controller responsible for the request url:

> org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'editorText' is not present

Anyone got an idea on how this flag may mess up the call ? (Before I've just had the flag set to `contentType: false`).

Complete Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/someUrl",
    type: "POST",
    data: new FormData($("#uploadForm")[0]),
    contentType: "text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
...
});
```

Comment: Do you have any other working software which accesses this backend service correctly?

Comment: If you want plain text from server, the use `contentType:false` and `dataType:text/plain`.

Comment: @CharlieH Yes, it's part of a System that works properly. If I let the `contentType` to false also this call works, it's just the encoding that gets messed up. That's why I tried to change it to `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`, but with that, the controller raises the above-mentioned exception.

Comment: You're sending binary `FormData`, so you need to set `contentType: false`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Oh I see, now that makes sense, thanks for the hint.

Comment: I would suggest you intercept your network traffic using a packet sniffer and see what the working application send. Then mimic the same in your ajax call.

Comment: setting `contentType` is you telling the server the kind of content _you_ are _sending_.  setting `dataType` is you giving jQuery a hint about what kind of data to expect back _from the server_. So sending form data and telling the server it's plain text isn't going to work. I think it's the `dataType` option you need to be setting instead. Separately the server needs actually set the correct type itself (slightly confusingly, on the server-side this is done by setting the content-type header as well, but in the context of a response instead of a request).